# Calculating total unique days with multiple entries and date range overlap

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having trouble with a utilization report I am trying to build in calculating the total number of unique days an Object was in service. My table contains a start and an end date for each ObjectCode but an object can have two entries in a single day, or have an overlap in the date range for example :

[Dates where a certain ObjectCode was on the job in July](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxIvj.png)

7/27 has two entries and therefore would give me an extra day if I were to sum this column by the selected month. How can I find a count for only the unique days in the selected month?

I've been using a sumx formula to find the total number of days for each month using my DaysOnJob column and likewise the utilization percentage for the selected month but with ObjectCodes like this one with multiple entries for multiple days I do not have a solution to finding the unique days on the job.

Comment: Your fact table (about usage) is missing the AssetID or whatever of whatever is being used. That's significant because you need some way of knowing what asset a date span belongs/refers to.

Comment: I think you can use `Unique` to get unique dates. But then you need to find out which value of the two under `DaysOnJob` you want for which you may need additional filtering

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to convert the (StartDate, EndDate) to a list of dates, and then return {EventIdentifier, TheDate,...} once you have that in a child table, you can just do a simple count per day.

I'm just a rookie at Lists though. (See youtube... I know Goodly does a really nice video on them). You basically convert the dates to numbers, and then create a custom function that turns that into a list {[StartDateNumber]..[EndDateNumber]}, and then you expand that so you get all the values {16,17,18...} and then you convert that column to a table and then back to dates. here's the video. https://youtu.be/tnjzIq7jinQ?si=aV8favVQp45C2K3j
yeah, I know they're gonna go nuts at me here, but that's the easiest way to explain it.
you'd convert CombinedStart and CombinedEnd to numbers, then convert that to a list, and then expand the list, and finally, convert the list column to individual values, and back to a date. Then if you join that column to your Calendar table, you just do a COUNTROWS('facttable') or maybe a DISTINCTCOUNT([AssetID]), you get the number of items in use on a given date.